# noUiSlider - Event when user tries to go beyond padding limits

Tags: nouislider

I have a slider with padding on the left side.
When the user tries to go beyond that padding (tries to slide or tap), I want to show an alert with some message.
Is there a way to figure out when this happens?

The on "slide" event does not work, as it does not return the moving direction or position when tapping on the bar.

Thank you!